# How to Get Error message from stored procedure into display on c#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in my database that is the following:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Cambiar_TerceroPedido_copy]
    @CodEmp as varchar(2) = '3',
    @TipoReg as varchar(2) = 'CF',
    @Pedido as integer,
    @NuevoCliente as varchar(10),
    @NuevoClienteEntrega as varchar(10) = null,
    @NuevoClienteFactura as varchar(10) = null,
    @NuevoClientePagoCobro as varchar(10) = null,
    @autorizador as varchar(10) = null,
    @error varchar(100) OUTPUT
AS
...

IF ((SELECT count(distinct T_FACTURAS.FACTURA)
        FROM T_FACTURAS INNER JOIN T_FACTURASL 
                ON T_FACTURAS.CODEMP = T_FACTURASL.CODEMP AND T_FACTURAS.TIPOREG = T_FACTURASL.TIPOREG AND T_FACTURAS.FACTURA = T_FACTURASL.FACTURA
        WHERE (T_FACTURAS.CODEMP = @CodEmp) 
                AND (T_FACTURAS.TIPOREG = @TipoReg) 
                AND (T_FACTURASL.NUMPED = @Pedido)
                AND (gg.dbo.getEsFechaControl(@CodEmp, 'MS', T_FACTURAS.FECHAF) = -1)
    ) > 0) BEGIN

    SET @error = 'ERROR!!!     El pedido tiene facturas asociadas. 1º debe eliminarlas' --+ cast (@CodEmp as varchar) + '/' + cast (@TipoReg as varchar) + '/' + cast (@Pedido as varchar) + '/'
    Print @error
    Return  
END
```

If I execute this code, I get an error in Microsoft SQL Server console, but I want to use this stored procedure in my C# code and I would like to know how I can get this error in a MessageBox?

Maybe store the error in a variable? And then adding parameters like this?

```
   strsql = "exec [dbo].[Cambiar_TerceroPedido_copy] '" + empresaGlobal.empresaID + "','" + c1 + "','" + c2numPed + "','" + c3provClient + "','" + c3provClient + "','" + c3provClient + "','" + c3provClient + "', 'JoseM'";
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strsql, conexion);
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@error", SqlDbType.Char, 500);
   cmd.Parameters["@error"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

Comment: `PRINT` is not an error. `RAISERROR` / `THROW` is for producing errors, and those will surface as `SqlException`s. `PRINT` can be intercepted with an event handler on `SqlConnection.InfoMessage`, but this should not be used for actual errors because it's easy to ignore (and the same applies to output parameter values, incidentally, so those are not ideal either).

Comment: According to your query and as already mentioned that's not an error, rather a user defined message. You would need to assign that to an `output` parameter... So for example: `SET @error = 'My error!'` Then after the command has ran, check the `Value` property of `@error` parameter; for example: `var message = cmd.Parameters["@error "].Value.ToString();` You may also have an error at `@error `, there's an extra space in that name...be sure to check that as it has to match.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I've updated the post with what I am doing, but I am having problems. This doesn't work, what could am I doing wrong?

Comment: @LuckWallace remove `Return`...as well as `Print` statement. Also your command should be `CommandType.StoredProcedure` and put just the SP name, and pass the params to it, well add them to the command.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ but why have I to remove Return? there are more conditions,

Comment: @LuckWallace how am I supposed to know there are more, this isn't in the code you posted. Then leave the return and follow what I mentioned above?

Comment: Your are pointlessly exposing your executions to SQL injection. Per the comment above, use `CommandType.StoredProcedure`, set the `CommandText` to `[dbo].[Cambiar_TerceroPedido_copy]` and pass your arguments as typed `SqlParameter` values. Then passing the `@error` parameter as an output parameter will start to work too.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ sorry, my bad. I updated the post again. But still not working, tells me: "Could not find stored procedure"

Comment: @LuckWallace `strsql` is still wrong, it *only* needs to include the SP name: `dbo.Cambiar_TerceroPedido_copy` and then you have to add all the params to the command.parameters collection. Please *re-read* my comments above. Also `Could not find stored procedure` means the SP doesn't exist are you sure it's there?

Answer (score 1):

> how I can get this error in a MessageBox

Add an event handler for [SqlConnection.InfoMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.infomessage?view=netframework-4.8).

> The InfoMessage event occurs when a message with a severity of 10 or
>   less is returned by SQL Server. Messages that have a severity between
>   11 and 20 raise an error and messages that have a severity over 20
>   causes the connection to close. For more information on SQL Server
>   error levels, see Database Engine Error Severities.

Comment: This technically answers the question, but is almost certainly not the approach the OP should use in this case -- given that there's already an output parameter for the error and they're apparently able to modify the procedure as well.

Comment: I agree.  PRINT should not be used to report failures or error conditions.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I concur as well.